# Get sender's mail address with macro

Tags: mutt

In Mutt's index view, I'd like to copy a sender's mail address to the system clipboard (using `xclip`, for example).

Is there a way to get at the sender's mail address of the currently selected mail using a macro or any other means?

Comment: The mutt keystrokes might be: `| grep ^From: | cut -d' ' -f2-`.  You can take it from there as to getting `xclip` to do what you want with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Using Python's [`email`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.html) library

I put this script in `~/.config/mutt/scripts/get_sender_email.py`:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
# Reads an email from standard in and prints the sender's email address.
# E.g.: sender@domain.com
# Call it from Bash like this: `./get_sender_email.py < your_email`

import sys
import email
from email import policy

# Read the email from standard in
msg = email.message_from_file(sys.stdin, policy=policy.default)

# See https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.headerregistry.html
sender_email_address = msg['from'].addresses[0].addr_spec

print(sender_email_address)
```

After making the file executable with `chmod +x get_sender_email.py`, I define a macro in my `muttrc`:

```
# Avoid the "Press any key to continue..." prompt
set wait_key=no

# Pipe the email content to the script which extracts the sender's email address.
# Then, put the email address into Wayland's clipboard
macro index,pager \cf\
  "| $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/mutt/scripts/get_sender_email.py\
   | wl-copy\n"\
  "Yank sender's email to clipboard"
```

While in Mutt's index or pager view, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> puts the sender's email address on the clipboard.

Since I'm on Wayland, I use [`wl-copy`](https://github.com/bugaevc/wl-clipboard) to write to the system clipboard.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12903893/python-imap-utf-8q-in-subject-string) or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504136/parsing-email-received-headers) for more on parsing emails.

## Old version using `grep`

The following is the original answer to this question. It uses a regular expression to get the part after the line starting with `From:`. The issue is that the part following `From:` can span multiple lines which the code below doesn't account for.

---

From the `muttrc`:

```
# Avoid the "Press any key to continue..." prompt
set wait_key=no

macro index,pager \cf "|grep -m 1 -oP '(?<=\^From: ).+' | (read after_from; echo \"\$after_from\" | grep -oP '(?<=<)(.+)(?=>)' || echo \"\$after_from\") | xclip -selection c\n" "Yank sender's email to clipboard"
```

Now <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> puts the sender's email address on the X system clipboard. Replacing `xclip -selection c` with `wl-copy` makes it work with Wayland.

We assume that the email address is on a line like this

```
From: Firstname Lastname <firstname.lastname@domain.com>
```

or like this

```
From: firstname.lastname@domain.com
```

Explanation of the macro:

- `|grep`: pipe the current email to grep.
- `-m 1`: grep will stop after it's matched the first line.
- `-o`: grep only prints the matched string, not the whole line.
- `P`: enable [Perl compatible regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions) in grep. We need this for the lookbehind in the regex.
- `'(?<=\^From: ).+'`: grep's regex. Get all characters after the line starting with "From: ". The `(?<=` part is a [positive lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) which means the line has to start with "From: ", but that string is not part of the match. The characters that come after are the matched string.
- At this point, grep prints either `Firstname Lastname <firstname.lastname@domain.com>` or `firstname.lastname@domain.com`.
- `| (read after_from;`: We pipe this string to the program [`read`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages//man1/read.1p.html) which saves the string in the variable `after_from`. The parenthesis starts a [subshell](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/subshells.html).
- `echo \"\$after_from\" | grep -oP '(?<=<)(.+)(?=>)'`: assuming the contents of `after_from` are `Firstname Lastname <firstname.lastname@domain.com>`, grep extracts the email address `firstname.lastname@domain.com`. `(?=>)` is a positive lookahead: after the matched string, there must be a `>`, but this closing angle bracket is not part of the matched string.
- If grep was succesful (exit code 0) in matching the email address inside the angle brackets, we pipe the email address to `xclip` and are done. `\n` is equivalent to hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> which makes Mutt execute the macro.
- On the other hand, if grep was not successful, which is the case when the part `after_from` is already an email address in the form `firstname.lastname@domain.com` (no angle brackets), we just send that address to the clipboard with `|| echo \"\$after_from\") | xclip -selection c`. The closing parenthesis marks the end of commands we execute in the subshell that we created. The [or operator](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/ops.html#ORREF) `||` means: If the command on the left side has failed (non-zero exit code), then execute the command on the right.

Note: For Mutt's macro, we have to escape the following characters with a backslash. If you want to use the command outside of Mutt, remove the backslashes:

- `^`
- `"`
- `$`