# Mutt - Tag all the mails sent by the sender's address with a macro

Tags: mutt

I want a macro that deletes all the mails that have been sent by the sender of  the mail under my cursor. So far I read about the tagging by pattern command and I [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/543447/get-senders-mail-address-with-macro) about yanking the sender's mail address, but I can't combine the two of them..